# Free mortarboard badge for no reason

Tags: bug, badges, daily-reputation-badges

I'm pretty sure I couldn't earn 200 rep recently, moreover I'm an inactive user for years, just occasionally returning here to have a look

[image]

Comment: Presumably due to https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/

Comment: hmm looks like mine issue is similar to yours [RC/SE Incorrectly notified of “Mortarboard” badge](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/831/6868) I found out that mine badge was awarded a year ago +/-1 day and just got wrong second notification yesterday...

Answer (score 3):

Oh, I should have noticed I have also got about 5,000 excess reputation there

I see, now question upvotes award 10 rep instead of 5 ...